# Drop target - where do I register the COleDropTarget variable if the view class doesn't have OnCreate?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The MSDN site says:

> From your view class's function that handles the WM_CREATE message (typically OnCreate), call the new member variable's Register member function. Revoke will be called automatically for you when your view is destroyed.

But I don't have an OnCreate function in the ChildView class.

I do have OnCreate in the CMainFrame class. Can I register it there? What are the ramifications?

**PLEASE NOTE:** I have it working for dropping files but I want to drop the text as a file, not at a cursor location like a text cut and paste, but rather I want the application to make a buffer to hold it, and I will treat it like a file.

TIA,

Harvey

Comment: It's got OnCreate().  CView inherits it from CWnd.

Comment: Thankyou, Just needed that kickstart.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I added the OnCreate override function, but it is not called. Now what?

Comment: Okay, I added the ON_WM_CREATE(). But now how do I get a pointer to the window to pass to droptarg.Register()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

In using F1 to get the syntax for OnDrop and the others, MSDN gave me:

```
virtual BOOL OnDrop(
   CWnd* pWnd,
   COleDataObject* pDataObject,
   DROPEFFECT dropEffect,
   CPoint point 
);
```

But the correct virtual function does not have the first parameter and should be:

```
virtual BOOL OnDrop(
   COleDataObject* pDataObject,
   DROPEFFECT dropEffect,
   CPoint point 
);
```

Same with the others. So I was never actually overriding the default functions.